# Take a row from one dataframe and insert into first row of another dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes. Both have the same structure with same columns/columnnames.

```
A-> dataframe with (v,w,x,y,z) columns ( Some values)
b -> dataframe with (v,w,x,y,z) columns ( All values)
```

I want to take the value from A dataframe and insert it into B dataframe.

Suppose when v=1, I need to fetch the rows from A dataframe where v==1 and insert into b dataframe. Also I want to insert it to the first row of the B Dataframe.

I tried the following,

b.insert(loc=1,values=A[A.v==1])

But getting errors

Can anybody help in doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate?

```
import pandas as pd
b = pd.concat([A[A.v==1],b])
```

Comment: I tried that already,

The code I used is,

b=pd.concat(a[a.v==1],b)

I am getting the following error,

TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: You have not closed the square bracket in the code. Where do we close it?

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed the last square bracket...now corrected.  I just tested this and it works.

Comment: thanks for the edit. Now it is working. But I am facing an issue here. Before this statement is used, many calculations were done and there were not error. but after introduction of this statement, I am getting errors for the calculations made after that. The following is the error,

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 714, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

You have any idea about this? I am not able to use the answer in my code

Comment: Without seeing the code I cannot really help.  However, I have seen this error when slicing dataframes/arrays via multiple criteria, e.g. a = a[ a.V==1 and a.Q==5], which is wrong.  This works: a = a[ (a.V==1) & (a.Q==5) ].  I would recommend checking for anything like that in your subsequent lines.

Comment: I am getting error in the second line here.

for j in range(1, len(b[1:])):
    if b.y[j]== 0 :
         b.y[j] = b.y[j-1]